# Multiple views for webpage depending on authentication status in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I am currently working on a developing a web application that people can use to browse through book reviews, but if they login they can post comments on the book reviews, or post their own reviews of books.

While I have implemented posting new reviews. I am do not understand how to modify the method in my views.py file that renders a book review such that if the user is logged in, in shows all previous comments, a form for the user to post a comment and a logout button, and if the user is not logged in it simply shows the book review and a log in button.

Comment: It seems like you can approach it either: 1) Create separate views for when the user is logged in vs when they are not logged in. 2) Add some logic to your templates to render the form to add a comment if they are logged in or render a button to login if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell if your user is logged in or not in your views like this:

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # logged in logic
        return render_to_response("loggedin_templates.html")
    else:
        # not logged in logic
        return render_to_response("not_loggedin_templates.html")
```

Or you can tell them in the templates like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <span>{{ user.username }}</span>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked for me. I quite like the in-template technique since I do not want to have 2 separate html files.